# Thymeleaf text output [

Tags: text, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf with template for TEXT to output some handcrafted text-files. Output should be

```
* smallText[description]
```

And I write in the thymeleaf template

```
* [(#{value}][[(#{value2}]]
```

But its not working and outputs (the "[" is missing)

```
* smallTextdescription
```

I also tried

```
* [(#{value}][ [(#{value2}] ]
```

But I do not want spaces behind the "[" Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the following syntax `th:text`?

```
/*[# th:text="|*${value}[${value2}]|"]*/
```

In this case the output is:

```
*smallText[description]
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Would you be so kind to replace `th:text="|${value}[${value2}]|"`with `[# th:text="|${value}[${value2}]|" /]` so the expression is complete and could be copypasted by anybody to his template?

Comment: I like this use of the [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) syntax, also. Minor points: What is the purpose of the forward slash (`/`) at the start? The asterisk `*` is missing from the output.

Comment: This is the explanation from the tutorial https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html:                           
The /*[[...]]*/ syntax, instructs Thymeleaf to evaluate the contained expression.
Being a javascript comment (/*...*/), our expression will be ignored when displaying the page statically in a browser.

Comment: @andrewjames sorry for the mistake, I forgot to enter * as character, however the output does not change

Comment: Regarding the `/`: I thought, from the question's context, that the question is about producing text files. The JavaScript notation you are referring to is not relevant in that context (using `TemplateMode.TEXT` to create text files). Your updated answer now throws a `TextParseException: Malformed template` error. (Also, the updated answer is not actually using the `/*[[...]]*/ ` syntax you refer to.) The core of your answer (using the literal substitution syntax) is good - but whether the JavaScript handler is right depends on the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to replace `[` with `[([)]` and `]` with `[(])]`.

```
* [(#{value})][([)][(#{value2})][(])]
```

Hoping for smarter and more elegant solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `TemplateMode.TEXT`, you can use the following syntax:

```
[#element ... /]
```

This is the text-mode equivalent of the more familiar HTML-based syntax, such as:

```
<div th:text=""...></div>
```

So, you can now write something like this in your text file (the Thymeleaf template):

```
[# th:text="'* ' + ${value} + '[' + ${value2} + ']'" /]
```

This produces:

```
* smallText[description]
```

NOTE - in my case I don't have any `#{...}` message values to test with, so I'm just using `${...}` variables in my test. But the same syntax applies to `#{...}` values.

See [textual template modes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#textual-template-modes) for more details.

Comment: This solution is working. Thank you. But I accepted the other answer because is simplier to read.